# How to optain an Optional with orElseGet()

Tags: java, java-8, return, option-type

This question is a beginner-level Java 8 question. School/College level assignment question.

The following method gives me the required `BigDecimal` answer :

```
public Optional<BigDecimal> getBillAmount(final String id) {
    return getBookAccount(id)
            .map(bookAccount -> {
                // do something and return BigDecimal
                return someBalance.get().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            });
}
```

The twist to add is - if in the above method `bookAccount` is not present then perform multiple steps and return another `Optional<BigDecimal>`.

To achieve this, I did the following, but it gives me an error because `orElseGet()` returns only `BigDecimal` and not `Optional<BigDecimal>`

```
public Optional<BigDecimal> getBillAmount(final String id) {
    return getBookAccount(id)
            .map(bookAccount -> {
                // do something and return BigDecimal
                return someBalance.get().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                 /*perform multiple actions related to the functional logic and then return a BigDecimal*/
                return someOptionalBigDecimal;
            });
}
```

The error I get is :

```
The method orElseGet(Supplier<? extends BigDecimal>) in the type
Optional<BigDecimal> is not applicable for the arguments (BigDecimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 9 you can use [`Optional.or()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) instead. It expects a *supplier* of *optional* as an argument and returns an *optional* object.

Method `or()` would be triggered only if it was invoked on an empty optional. And you can apply `or()` in the chain as many times as you need, providing one alternative after another.

If we imagine that *optional* is a *box*, then `or()` checks whether the *box* is empty and if it is the case it delivers another *box*.

`orElseGet()` is different, it doesn't give you a *box*, instead it hands you the *contents* as is. For that reason, it expects a *supplier* of type `T` (not a supplier of optional). And you can't invoke methods defined in the optional class after applying `orElseGet()` - the *box* is gone, now there's an object of type `T`.

That's how it would look like with `Optional.or()`:

```
public Optional<BigDecimal> getBillAmount(final String id) {
    
    return getBookAccount(id)
        .map(bookAccount -> {
            // do something and return BigDecimal
            return someBalance.get().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        })
        .or(() -> {
            /*perform multiple actions related to the functional logic and then return a BigDecimal*/
            return someOptionalBigDecimal;
        });
}
```

With Java 8 there's no possibility to build a similar method chain. I would probably do it like this:

```
public Optional<BigDecimal> getBillAmount(final String id) {
    
    Optional<BigDecimal> result = getBookAccount(id)
        .map(bookAccount -> {
            // do something and return BigDecimal
            return someBalance.get().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        });
    
    if (!result.isPresent()) result = resortToAnotherOption(id);
    
    return result;
}

public Optional<BigDecimal> resortToAnotherOption(final String id) {

    /*perform multiple actions related to the functional logic and then return a BigDecimal*/
    return someOptionalBigDecimal;
}
```

Comment: This requires Java 9, with Java 8 you'll have to resort to `map` with `ifPresent()` check.

Comment: isn't .or()  a java 9 feature? Unfortunately , I need to make it work on java8

Comment: @Tiya Please feel encouraged to use the experts in this community as a recommendation for your instructor to update to at least Java 9 in the future. It fixed a _lot_ of missing pieces in the new streams/related APIs, such as `or` and `ifPresentOrElse`.

Comment: @Tiya As @Kayaman has pointed out if with Java 8 there's no way build a chein in this case. You have to check where the result is present after invoking `someBalance.get()...`.

Comment: @Tiya Provided an example for Java 8.